# Batch script wont exit

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

My batch script contains this code:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "git fetch -q --all -p"
```

When I run it by double clicking, or when started by the task scheduler it wont close the window after it's done.
I've tried Start "" "C:..., Exit 0, cmd \c,GOTO :EOF and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason calling using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe` leads to two ssh-agent.exe processes that won't stop even after calling exit. So my solution was to instead use the git command which calls `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe` and does not leave ssh-agent.exe processes running and allows the command window to close.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you're opening a window which is calling `sh.exe`, opening it in another window. There is nothing to tell that window the close after the first one does.

Try adding `& exit` to the end of your git command.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i -c "git fetch -q --all -p & exit"
```

Comment: Adding & exit made it so sh would logout but the command prompt still wont exit. Whats interesting is that if i launch command prompt and run the command Exit won't work afterwards, I'm assuming the sh process doesn't actually stop so the command window doesn't allow me to exit since other commands work fine.

Comment: Also I've just noticed that i have a ton of ssh-agent processes still running so i guess that the culprit.